# Clearing the terminal before displaying MOTD

Tags: ssh, debian, debian-squeeze

When I connect to my SSH server, it prompts me for the user name and password. After I have authenticated, it will display my MOTD, then show user prompt, like this:

```
Using username "root".
Authenticating with public key "everssh"
this is my motd
root@debian:~#
```

I want to edit some file so that the screen is cleared before the MOTD prints (so basically calling the `clear` command would do). I heard that the MOTD is displayed by using `cat /etc/motd` in a startup file, however after searching around I can't find where it is called from.

Does anyone know how I can find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The motd is indeed taken from the `/etc/motd` file, but it is *not* displayed using `cat` or any other external command: the SSH server does it internally, using the `pam_motd` PAM module.

If you want the screen to be cleared when the motd is displayed <sub>(wouldn't it be annoying, though?)</sub>, you add use the ANSI sequences `ESC [ H` and `ESC [ J` to the beginning of `/etc/motd` contents.

- To insert the `ESC` character in Vim, press <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>; in Nano, press <kbd>Alt+V</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>.
- Insert `[` and `H` using <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Shift+H</kbd>.
- Repeat to insert `ESC [ J`.

Comment: Wasn't totally clear to me at first, but the line should look like this in the editor: "^[[H^[[J". +1 for a good answer.